# Capybara expect page.selector to_have

Tags: rspec, capybara, rspec-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I need to validate the presence of some text in a specific part of the page.

`expect(page).to` will output too much text, it is especially annoying for the page which hold the terms of agreement, which are always so long.

I'd like to transform `expect(page).to(have_text(` into something like `expect('#id').to(have_text(...)`

I cannot figure out how to select the part of the page referenced by ID. Should I write my `expect(page)` inside a `within('#id')` ?

EDIT : if possible, a solution that works against nested tags

```
<div id="id">
  <span class="nested">...</span>
  Text I want to check with have_text()
</div>`
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You have multiple choices here, either

```
section = find(:css, '#id') #the :css may be optional depending on your Capybara.default_selector setting
# or - section = find_by_id('id')
expect(section).to have_text(...)
```

or

```
expect(page).to have_css('#id', text: '...')
```

or

```
expect(page).to have_selector(:id, 'id', text: '...')
```

depending on whether or not you need the element for other things.

Comment: Do those solutions also work against tags which do not have just text but also nested tags ?

`<div id="targetId"><span class="nested">...</span>Text I want to check </div>`

Comment: @CyrilDuchon-Doris Yes, by default the text option matches a substring of any visible text inside the element - `expect(page).to haves_css('#targetId', text: 'Text I want to check')`